# Activity must not be null error , Kotlin android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, kotlin, fragment

I have 4 fragments in Tablayout "Home" ,"Market" , "Office" and "Admin" and 3 table in Sqlite for "Home" , "Office" and "Market" In Admin fragment admin takes the data with table name and store in its respective table and display in recyclerView of each respective fragment but it shows activity must not be null

> Admin_Fragment

```
package com.example.muhammadrizwan.deafanddumbcommunicationaid.Fragments


import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ImageView
import com.example.muhammadrizwan.deafanddumbcommunicationaid.Model.Data
import com.example.muhammadrizwan.deafanddumbcommunicationaid.Model.DbHelper

import com.example.muhammadrizwan.deafanddumbcommunicationaid.R
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 *
 */
class Admin_Fragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var image: ImageView
    private lateinit var text1: EditText
    private lateinit var text2: EditText
    private lateinit var addBtn: Button
    private lateinit var Txttitle: String
    private lateinit var Iname: String
    private var GalleryCode: Int = 200
    private var CameraCode: Int = 100
    lateinit var stream : ByteArrayOutputStream
    lateinit var ByteImage : ByteArray
    var database = DbHelper(activity)
    var sql = database.writableDatabase
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin_, container, false)

        var data = Data()
        data.text = Txttitle
        data.Image = ByteImage
        data.InterfaceName = Iname
        database.InsertData(data)
        image = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
        text1 = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.title)
        text2 = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.name)
        addBtn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.AddBtn)
        addBtn.setOnClickListener {
            validate()
        }
        return  view
    }

    private fun validate() {
        if(!text1.text.isEmpty())
        {
            Txttitle = text1.text.trim().toString()

            if(!text2.text.isEmpty())
            {
                 Iname = text2.text.trim().toString()
            }else{
              text2.setError("Enter Interface Name")
            }
        }
        else{
            text1.setError("Enter Title")
        }
        image.setOnClickListener {
                var builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                builder.setTitle("Make Choice")
                var option = arrayOf("Capture","Gallery")
                builder.setItems(option,object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener
                {
                    override fun onClick(p0: DialogInterface?, p1: Int) {
                        if(option[p1].equals("Capture"))
                        {
                            openCamera()
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            openGallery()
                        }
                    }

                })
            builder.show()
        }

    }



    private fun openGallery() {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            startActivityForResult(intent,GalleryCode)
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),GalleryCode)
        }
    }
    private fun openCamera() {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
                var intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivityForResult(intent,CameraCode)
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA),CameraCode)
        }

    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when(requestCode)
        {
            CameraCode->
            {
                if(grantResults.size>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    openCamera()
                }
            }
            GalleryCode->
            {
                if(grantResults.size>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    openGallery()
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when(requestCode)
        {
            CameraCode->
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                var bitmap = data?.extras?.get("data")
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap as Bitmap)
                stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream)
                ByteImage = stream.toByteArray()
            }
            GalleryCode->
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                var Uri = data!!.data
                var bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.contentResolver,Uri)
                stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream)
                ByteImage = stream.toByteArray()
            }
        }
    }





}
```

> DbHelper

```
package com.example.muhammadrizwan.deafanddumbcommunicationaid.Model

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.widget.Toast

class DbHelper(var ctx:Context) :  SQLiteOpenHelper(ctx,"Deaf and Dumb",null,1) {

    val TableHome = "Home"
    val TableOffice = "Office"
    val TableMarket = "Market"
//    val HomeText = "Home Text"
//    val HomeImage = "Blob"
//    val OfficeText = "Office Text"
//    val OfficeImage = "Blob"


    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val TableHome = "CREATE TABLE $TableHome (Text STRING , Image BLOB)"
        val TableOffice = "CREATE TABLE $TableOffice (Text STRING , Image BLOB)"
        val TableMarket = "CREATE TABLE $TableMarket (Text STRING , Image BLOB)"
        db!!.execSQL(TableHome)
        db!!.execSQL(TableOffice)
        db!!.execSQL(TableMarket)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {

    }

    fun InsertData(data: Data) {
        var dbHelper = DbHelper(ctx)
        var database = dbHelper.writableDatabase
        var values = ContentValues()
        values.put("Text", data.text)
        values.put("Image", data.Image)
        values.put("Interface Name", data.InterfaceName)
        if (data.InterfaceName.equals("HOME")) {
            database.insert("$TableHome", null, values)
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Inserted in $TableHome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else if (data.InterfaceName.equals("OFFICE")) {
            database.insert("$TableOffice", null, values)
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Inserted in $TableHome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else if (data.InterfaceName.equals("MARKET")) {
            database.insert("$TableMarket", null, values)
        }
        dbHelper.close()
    }

    fun getHomeData(): List<Data> {
        var HomeList = ArrayList<Data>()
        var dbHelper = writableDatabase
        val sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM $TableHome"
        var cursor = dbHelper.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null)
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            do {
                var data = Data()
                data.text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Text"))
                data.Image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("Image"))
            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        return HomeList
    }

    fun getofficeData(): List<Data> {
        var OfficeList = ArrayList<Data>()
        var dbHelper = writableDatabase
        val sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM $TableOffice"
        var cursor = dbHelper.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null)
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            do {
                var data = Data()
                data.text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Text"))
                data.Image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("Image"))
            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        return OfficeList
    }

    fun getMarketData(): List<Data> {
        var MarketList = ArrayList<Data>()
        var dbHelper = writableDatabase
        val sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM $TableMarket"
        var cursor = dbHelper.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null)
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            do {
                var data = Data()
                data.text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Text"))
                data.Image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("Image"))
            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        return MarketList
    }

}
```

> Error

```
Process: com.example.muhammadrizwan.deafanddumbcommunicationaid, PID: 4181
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: activity must not be null
        at com.example.muhammadrizwan.deafanddumbcommunicationaid.Fragments.Admin_Fragment.<init>(Admin_Fragment.kt:48)
        at com.example.muhammadrizwan.deafanddumbcommunicationaid.adapter.ViewPagerAdapter.getItem(ViewPagerAdapter.kt:28)
```

Comment: You can't reference `context` or `activity` until `onAttach()` has been called.

Comment: Where to call onAttach ??

Comment: `DbHelper(activity)` you can;t use the activity before onAttach

Comment: Where to use onAttach ??

Comment: `onAttach ` is a fragment's lifecycle callback

Comment: can't understand

Comment: then you probably need to pass through some `Fragment` basics in Android.

Comment: Ok , Can you please tell me that if we have multiple tables in sqlite and and we want to add data in specific table which users enter for example , we have "Home" , "Market" and "Office" table and each table have two fieid text and image now if user select Office then data will be added to office table , How ??